# Share an enum between projects

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I'm developing a solution with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

I have an enum that I have to share between many projects. I only need to share the enum, not the other classes that are in this project.

Do I need to create a class library with the enum to enable sharing it between other projects?

I think this is too much: create a project for an enum only.

This enum class is not updated very often. Now I have two copies of this enum in two different projects. The problem appears now, when I have to update it.

Comment: There is no much else you can do apart from having a share project with the enum or make one project reference the other, however because enums can be ints, they can be shared via a primitive

Comment: Will this enum class be updated frequently?

Comment: _Do I need to create a class library with the enum to enable sharing it between other projects?_ Yes, that is how you do it.

Comment: In the Many projects, are they referencing each other internally? then you should create enum in the project which is being referenced.

Comment: There's gotta be some kind of interface that takes the enum, right? Shouldn't you expose that as well? If you don't have such an interface, why not just declare it in every project? Also, I don't think having just one enum in a class library is problematic.

Comment: I have updated the question with the details about if the enum is updated very often.

Comment: The best and cleanest thing can do is to make a different assembly which contains that enum. and add reference of that assembly in every required projects.

Comment: "I only need to share the enum" sounds strange. The exact relation between the projects does matter. If there is a clear definition possible, you could consider strings or ints for encoding. But it will be an important contract that has to be well defined and guarded.

Comment: Create a new project called common and be done with it, you never know you might find more stuff to put in there for your business layer later

Comment: My answer with linking .cs files was incorrect. Thanks @bommelding.

Comment: I only said it needed some safeguards.

Comment: As possible solution I can propose to keep single .cs file with enum, and add it to 2 (or more) projects. You will not need to update 2 (or more) files, when you need a change.

Comment: Two projects shares same domain type(enum in your case) - this a sign that later projects will share more then one enum. Project is just another folder with project file in it. Projects, classes, files are our(developers) tools to build application - use right tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I think this is too much: create a project for an enum only.

This is not quote a neutral question if you already suggest an answer. :)

Secondly, this kind of topic would be better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ IMHO.

But for the question: you can avoid extracting a project with a single enum if you handle it as a usual data contract: you define the enum at both sides, and implement a mapping between the two.

It has drawbacks of course: you need to duplicate your enum and do some serialization and deserialization. The trivial way of doing this is to transferring the underlying int value or the enum field name and re-map it on the other side.

You did not provide any further details so I cannot tell whether really this would be the the better solution but generally if there are no (maybe just architecturally) remote components involved, then I would go for the separate project (maybe named Common or Model), which can be referenced by all parties. However, I can hardly imagine a data model where only a single enum is the only type to store.